# alphavantage API not able to work for canadian ETF and stocks (TSX)

Tags: finance, alpha-vantage

URL:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=XIU.TO&outputsize=full&apikey=<API_KEY>

It seemed to stop working for all "*.TO". this worked a few weeks ago. Anyone know what has changed? or if they decide not to support TSX.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and can confirm it still works for me. maybe check if there is a typo on your API KEY

Comment: I just also checked, it worked. So it may have been done for maintanance

Answer (score 0):

Just contacted Alphavantage.

- quick and useful response = impressed!
- use XIU.TRT (.TRT for Toronto, and not .TO or .TSX)